# Possible values of VerifierFlags

Tags: windows, application-verifier

I've enabled application verifier on my application, and it created a registry value `VerifierFlags` with value `0x80000000`

Where do I find a list of possible VerifierFlags values? I tried to lookup online, [the only thing I found is about drives](https://support.microsoft.com/en-hk/help/244617/using-driver-verifier-to-identify-issues-with-windows-drivers-for-adva).

Does anyone know?

Comment: Implementation details are generally not documented. What do you need this information for?